# Compare array variable with list of possible values

Tags: powershell, comparison, operator-keyword

I need to compare a value from an array with a list of possible results, and then return a value in a variable depending on whether the list is matched or not.

i.e.  I have an array called `$ErroredBackup` with a column "status"
I need to compare each `$ErroredBackup.Status` with a list of possible numbers, and if it matches set a $output variable to Error.  If it doesn't match, leave the `$output` variable as is (I set it to Pass to start with)

I've tried using `-contain`, but that seems to be the other way round - comparing an array with a single value, not comparing a single value with a list.

This works for a single value:

```
$Output="Pass"
$ErroredBackups = Import-Csv C:\temp\NetBackupJobs_GS.csv
                    foreach ($ErroredBackup in $ErroredBackups) {If ($ErroredBackup.status -eq 26) {$Output="Error"}}
```

But I need a range of values:

```
$Output="Pass"
$ErroredBackups = Import-Csv C:\temp\NetBackupJobs_GS.csv
                    foreach ($ErroredBackup in $ErroredBackups) {If ($ErroredBackup.status -eq 2,26,50,48,2820,4239) {$Output="Error"}}
```

What I'd like is for the `foreach` loop to go through the array and if it finds any of the listed values in the .status column it changes the value of `$output` to "Error", else it leaves it as "Pass".  The end result of this will be to write either Pass or Error to a text file and then use our network monitoring tool to parse that file and alert if it finds Error.

Comment: take a look at the `-in` and the `-contains` array operators. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lee_Dailey said, the `in`-operator is what you need. Below is a simplified example

```
$errors = 1,2,3,5,6
$ErroredBackup = 4
if ($ErroredBackup -in $errors) { "Error" } else { "Pass" }
```

Since `4` is **not** in `$errors`, it returns `Pass`

```
$errors = 1,2,3,5,6
$ErroredBackup = 5
if ($ErroredBackup -in $errors) { "Error" } else { "Pass" }
```

Since `5` **is** in `$errors`, it returns `Error`

Answer (score 0):

Use an `-OR` statement in your condition.

```
$ErroredBackups = Import-Csv "C:\temp\NetBackupJobs_GS.csv"

foreach ($ErroredBackup in $ErroredBackups.status) {
    If (@($ErroredBackup -eq "2" -OR $ErroredBackup -eq "26" -OR $ErroredBackup -eq "50" -OR $ErroredBackup -eq "48" -OR $ErroredBackup -eq "2820" -OR $ErroredBackup -eq "4239")) {
        $Output="Error"
        write-host $Output
    } else{
        $Output="Pass"
        write-host $Output
    }
}
```

**--OR--**

You can use `-match`

```
$errorArr = "2","26","50","48","282","4239"

$ErroredBackups = Import-Csv "C:\temp\NetBackupJobs_GS.csv"

foreach ($ErroredBackup in $ErroredBackups.status) {
    if ($errorArr -match $ErroredBackup){$Output="Error"}else{$Output="Pass"}
    write-host $Output

}
```

**--OR--**

Use `compare-object` and then do a conditional check on the SideIndicator

```
$errorArr = "2","26","50","48","2820","4239"

$ErroredBackups = Import-Csv "C:\temp\NetBackupJobs_GS.csv"

foreach ($ErroredBackup in $ErroredBackups.status) {
    $Output = compare-object $errorArr $ErroredBackup 
    IF ($Output.SideIndicator -eq '=>'){write-host 'Pass'}else{write-host 'Error'} 

}
```