# Using an If statement to set a variable, but not change it if a condition isn't met?

Tags: powershell, variables, if-statement

I'm trying to set an output variable from an IF statement but only when it's condition is met, but leave the variable untouched if the condition isn't met.  For some reason, the IF statement is changing the variable even when the condition isn't met.  How do I tell an IF statement to do nothing if it's condition fails?

I originally started with the IF statement setting $Output = "Error" in it's script block, but that just sets it to fail even when it shouldn't.

```
$Output = "Pass"

$ErrorCodes = 2, 26, 50, 48, 2820, 4239
$ErroredBackups = Import-Csv C:\temp\NetBackupJobs_GS.csv

foreach ($ErroredBackup in $ErroredBackups) { 
    $Output = if ($ErroredBackup.status -in $ErrorCodes) { 
        "Error"
    }
}
$Output
```

Sample of the CSV:

jobid,started,status
334382,17/07/2019 16:35,0

I keep getting $Output as blank, when it should either be "Error" or "Pass"

Comment: Well, you keep overwriting `$Output` inside the loop, so it'll always reflect whether the _last_ csv entry has a `status` code in your list of error codes or not. Are you trying to figure out if _any_ of the jobs had _any_ of the error codes?

Comment: Exactly that.  I have a list of jobs from NetBackup, with their jobID, startdate and exit code (status) in a CSV.  I'm trying to loop through the array and end up with a variable that says either Pass or Error depending on if any of the Status codes match the error list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare array variable with list of possible values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57099336/compare-array-variable-with-list-of-possible-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the assigment (`$Output = ...`) inside the `if` block:

```
if ($ErroredBackup.status -in $ErrorCodes) { 
    $Output = "Error"
}
```

An alternative, perhaps more PowerShell-idiomatic approach would be leveraging `Where-Object` to find "truly failed" backups:

```
$ErrorCodes = 2, 26, 50, 48, 2820, 4239
$ErroredBackups = Import-Csv C:\temp\NetBackupJobs_GS.csv

if($ErroredBackups |Where-Object status -in $ErrorCodes){
    # At least one backup job must have had a terrible error code
    "Error"
}
else{
    # None found, pass
    "Pass"
}
```